# how to programmatically enable floating notification in android device using code

Tags: android, push-notification

Be informed we are using heads up notification in our android app up to alert our users. Code is working fine as long as we manually go to settings and enable floating notification in our Xiaomi Redmi 9a Device. Otherwise, it works just like regular notification with just icon on top of status bar waiting for us to pull it down to see the message

Based on some threads, we tried using this line to switch on floating notification by default

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

But ,end result is same. But seriously speaking, how can we expect a user to go down so deep in settings and enable it. I mean its ridiculous. Is there any way we can get around this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the permission in the app manifest

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`
2. Check the Permission

   `ContexCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED { sendNotification(this) }`

Comment: Thanks for replying, its indeed a viable solution, but according to android documentation, this permissions will only work in android 13, which has just been released as beta. So unless devices have android 13 version, this won't work. Is there any way we can get this work in android < 11 versions.